# Having trouble with mouse pointer dissapearing after login

Tags: mouse, graphics, intel, greeter

There's a recent bug for ubuntu based distros which have Intel graphics boards. You can read description here, but basically mouse pointer dissapears after login

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604

I can see that Elementary released a fix for it. I've updated my Freya install with latest updates and still have the bug.

Is there a way to know which is that patch and try to download/apply it manually?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Based on that bug report, it looks like the issue wasn't actually resolved in Freya's updates

Comment: Yea @wolf , lots of guys in comments are asking to mark it as confirmed not patched/solved

Comment: Yep, I was one of them. Have you tried upgrading to Loki or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this which I found on the net:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/mouse-pointer-disappears-after-switching-users/

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be **patched in Loki**, if you can upgrade.

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604) is the manual fix that worked for someone else:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(No worries, this [does not](https://askubuntu.com/q/215267/49899) upgrade the distribution to Loki.)